# How I use a lowercase filepath in Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a macro that takes the value of a cell which should be a file and then converts it to a csv file using xlwings and a VBS script. This macro is assigned to a button.

Below is an example function:

```
import subprocess
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def extract_excel_sheet_to_csv(filename, sheet_name, working_dir, csv_filename):
    wb = Workbook.caller()
    new_filename = os.path.join(working_dir, filename)

    cmd = ''.join(['cscript extract_excel_sheet_to_csv.vbs "',
                new_filename, '" "', sheet_name, '" "',
                working_dir, '" "', csv_filename, '"'])
    cmd = cmd.encode("utf8")

    subprocess.call(cmd)

filename = Range(sheet_arxikh, status_cell).value # Example data.xlsb
sheet_name = u"Αρχείο"
working_dir = os.path.dirname(wb.fullname)
csv_filename = "data.csv"

convert_file(filename, sheet_name, working_dir, csv_filename)
```

The wb.fullname gives something like this: `"c:\projects\buy_sell\data.xlsb"`, so the working_dir would be `"c:\projects\buy_sell\"`. This creates a problem in the filepaths using the following VBS script. If I use `r"c:\projects\buy_sell"` it works fine.

This is the VBS script I use:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
sheet_name = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
dir_name = Wscript.Arguments.Item(2)
file_name = Wscript.Arguments.Item(3)

WScript.Echo src_file
WScript.Echo sheet_name
WScript.Echo dir_name + "\" +  file_name + ".csv"
REM WScript.Echo dir_name
REM WScript.Echo file_name

Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False

Dim objWorkbook
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(src_file)

objWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Copy
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dir_name + "\" +  file_name + ".csv", 6

objWorkbook.Close False
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: `os.path.dirname(r"c:\projects\buy_sell\data.xlsb"")` gives `r"c:\projects\buy_sell` (no trailing \) in python 2 & 3 on my machine. But if its a problem for you, preferable fix the vbscript to handle dirnames with `\` or trim it in the python code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. The title mentions lowercase, but all the filenames you mention are all lowercase already. Is there some issue with `\b` being parsed to `\x08` or something? I don't understand what is different between the path you say is working and the one that does not. Can you print their `repr`s?